# Sense of Upper Confidence Bound algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, math, data-science

I watched a tutorial about UCB at Udemy and didn't saw the sense of using that algorithm.

For example, you have 10 commercial and you know 10000 user's behavior (click or not). You use UCB to know the best commercial of those 10. But you also can count all clicks and get the same result.

Data example 
[image]

Result of **UCB** (4th ad is the best) - teacher's result

[image]

Result of **sum of clicks** (4th ad is the best)
[image]

As you see there no difference. You get the same result, 4th ad is the best.

Maybe the teacher gave a bad example? And are there is the case when using UCB makes sense? 
Or I didn't quite understand.

Can you help me with that? Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

I found your example on this [site](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/reinforcement-multi-armed-bandit-scratch-python/) maybe it gives you another way of seeing it. From the read and what I understand, upper bound confidence algorithm will greatly favor the 4th ad. Only using an histogram maybe works here but you could foresee a case where the 7th ad is so close that it could also be the optimal ad to show but you'd need even more data to be sure you're making the right call.

Comment: Thank for your answer. An example on that site is exactly the same as at Udemy. And if you just count all clicks you will see the same graph as mine. The goal of UCB finds the best option (as I understand). Is counting clicks of each ad doesn't give the same result?